# Am I removing 6 grid points on both boundaries of a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

i am trying to index the interior points by excluding the first 6 points and last 6 points of a given array

I am checking the length of the list and seeing if the new grid is 12 points smaller

To do this I am doing

list_example = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,..... ,12,13,14] # this has a len of 14

print(len(list_example[6:-6]))

this would return a list with the 6 points on both sides removed, but for some reason I am thrown off. Am i starting the new list at the 7th point and stopping at the point that is located 7 spaces away from the end?

I am new to python so the indexing is throwing me a bit off

Comment: If you already recognize that 6 elements are removed on both sides, what's the issue?

Comment: My sanity seems to be the only issue here *sigh* thanks for such a quick response! Thesis has been getting to me and the end is near

Comment: indexing start from 0

Comment: "for some reason I am thrown off".  *Explain* what output you got and what you expected.  The result should be 2.  The slice returns `[7, 8]`.